# jQuery form post cross domain Amazon S3 ie < 10, error "aborted"

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3, cross-domain, jquery-forms-plugin, form-post

Hi does anyone know how to post multipart forms cross domain to Amazon S3 (for instance) in IE 8, 9?

We have used the jQuery forms-plugin. Maybe it doesn't support the XDomainRequest object? Is jQuery forms the wrong way to go?

We have configured the Amazon S3 bucket to allow origin * for post, get and thus working in all other browsers even IE 10.

It begins the posting. From which i can tell, it displays posting status message against the amazon url, which is shown down to the left in the browser. But then it triggers the error return function (specified in the ajax options) with the status "aborted". Nothing else. So it seems like the request is aborted. The file never reaches Amazon, if the error would come from Amazon it would be a little more detailed i'd guess.

I've tried posting from https also (as someone suggested somewhere, since amazon upload url uses https). No difference.

Any ideas?

/John

Comment: I'm having almost the same problem uploading an image from ie9. But the funny thing is the file actually gets uploaded correctly to the bucket. But the request ends up as "Aborted" so the callbacks get mucked up. Did you find anything to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct - your plugin will not support XDomainRequest because it's based on jQuery.

[jQuery doesn't include support for XDR:](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283#comment:43)

> Summary of the XDomainRequest issue:
>
> - jQuery does not include XDomainRequest support because there are  numerous and serious limitations to XDR.

IE version 10 [supports CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Browser_support), but previous versions don't and use XDR:

> MSHTML/Trident 6.0 (Internet Explorer 10) has native support. MSHTML/Trident 4.0 & 5.0 (Internet Explorer 8 & 9) provides partial support via the XDomainRequest object.

---

You could try adding [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Ovea/cors) to your site to see if it resolves your issue. From the README:

> jQuery plugin which transparently adds Cross Origin Resource Sharing
> (CORS) amongst browsers, including IE8+

---

**EDIT**: If that doesn't work, you could add the [following snippet](http://graphicmaniacs.com/note/getting-a-cross-domain-json-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8-and-later/) which attempts the same modification:

```
  if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {
 
  // override default jQuery transport
  jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
      try { return new XDomainRequest(); }
      catch(e) { }
  };
 
  // also, override the support check
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
 
}
```